# dropdown in a foreach loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, foreach

I have a list in a foreach loop and in each one there is an option to edit from a dropdown select box however when adding more than one of these select boxes the whole thing stops working when clicking the service and dropping the options down.

This is the code:

```
<select id="aroptions" name="aroptions" data-id="<?php echo $get['id'];?>">
       <option value="none">Please Select your service</option>
       <option class="tw" value="artw">Option 1</option>
       <option class="aiop" value="araiop">Option 2</option>
       <option class="rr" value="rr">Option 3</option>
       <option class="aw" value="aw">Option 4</option>
       <option class="gr" value="gr">Option 5</option>
    </select>

    <div class="twsettings" data-id="<?php echo $get['id'];?>" style="display:none">
    <div class="form-group row" style="padding: 10px;">
        <label for="username" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">
             Username:
        </label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <input type="text" class="form-control-plaintext input-lg" style="height: 39px; width:100%;" 
              name="twusername" id="twusername" size="45" />
        </div>
        <br><br>
        <label for="username" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">
            Series Name:
        </label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <input type="text" data-id="<?php echo $get['id'];?>" class="form-control-plaintext input-lg" style="height: 39px; width:100%;" 
              name="twseries" id="twseries" size="45" />
        </div>
        <br><br>
        <label for="default" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">
            Set as Default:
        </label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
        <input type="checkbox" name="main_ar_tw" data-id="<?php echo $get['id'];?>" style="width: 5%;height: 34px;" value="Yes"/><br>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

The non working js is below

```
 $('select').change(function(){
if ($(this).val() == "tw"){
    $(this).closest('.twsettings').css("display", "none");
    $(this).closest('.twsettings').removeClass("show");
} });
```

`Now i understand that for this to work each dropdown selection has to have a unique id otherwise they will all dropdown at the same time hence the data-id value but for the life of me i cannot remember how to do it.

Any help would be appreciated :)

I've created a fiddle for you to play around with. Note: The data-setting-id is different in each iteration of the loop. JSFiddle][1](https://jsfiddle.net/kuLm3xn1/) (currently the dropdown will only function on the first option as the others are not added in the fiddle)

Comment: I'd start by appending the PHP id (the one you're already assigning to the data-id attribute) to the `select` element id to make each unique. See if that helps.

Comment: This might be useful to you. You can use AJAX to populate a select box via JSON response.  I've documented it pretty well.
https://jsfiddle.net/difster/9cxy7dkt/

Comment: You have way too many unclosed questions, IMHO.

Comment: [Why is ***“Can someone help me?”*** not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).

Comment: change `div.twsettings`'s data-id attribute to `data-setting-id` and try following:
`var dataId = $(this).attr('data-id');
var $elm = $('*[data-setting-id="' + dataId + '"]');
$elm.css("display", "none");
$elm.removeClass("show");`

Comment: Except nowhere in that title does it say "Can someone help me" and not sure "any help would be appreciated" at the end of the issue is the same.

Comment: That didn't seem to do anything @im_tsm

Comment: You will get the twsettings div in `$elm`, now you can do whatever you want with that div. Here I have made the div visible: https://jsfiddle.net/kuLm3xn1/2/

Comment: Yes but if you see when the second dropdown option is added it opens both. https://jsfiddle.net/kuLm3xn1/3/

Comment: Try to imagine 5 options in the select with 5 divs set to display:none and the foreach loop shows 3 of them so 3 select boxes with 15 options in total. How do you separate the unique ids to show the right dropdown on the right list?

Comment: Well, did you actually read (and try) the very first comment?

Comment: I would appreciate if you could elaborate on that first comment Patrick as i am not too great with the js that would be needed to make it work :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first change that I'd make is to make your `select` elements have unique IDs:

`<select id="aroptions<?php echo $get['id'];?>" name="aroptions" data-id="<?php echo $get['id'];?>">`

That alone isn't going to do a whole lot for you though.  First, you need to make sure that you're hiding all the divs before you show any of them.  Then you need to make sure that when you're selecting an option, you use both the selected value *and* the select element's ID to determine which div to show.

For the hiding, I've given each settings div a class of `option-group` and in the Javascript we will run `$(".option-group").hide();`.

To show the correct settings div, we'll concatenate the corresponding option value with the `select` element ID to create the div's `data-setting-id` such as  `data-setting-id="artw<?php echo $get['id'];?>"` and `data-setting-id="araiop<?php echo $get['id'];?>"`  You will need to follow this pattern for each option group div.

Then in the Javascript, we do the same and concatenate the selected option with the element ID: `var $elm = $('*[data-setting-id="' + selectedOpt + dataId + '"]');`

Here's how I updated the output that you provided in the fiddle.

```
<select id="aroptions123" name="aroptions" data-id="123">
           <option value="none">Please Select your service</option>
           <option class="tw" value="artw">Option 1</option>
           <option class="aiop" value="araiop">Option 2</option>
           <option class="rr" value="rr">Option 3</option>
           <option class="aw" value="aw">Option 4</option>
           <option class="gr" value="gr">Option 5</option>
        </select>

<div class="option-group twsettings" data-setting-id="artw123" style="display:none">
  <div class="form-group row" style="padding: 10px;">
    <label for="username" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">
                 Username:
            </label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <input type="text" class="form-control-plaintext input-lg" style="height: 39px; width:100%;" name="twusername" id="twusername" size="45" />
    </div>
    <br><br>
    <label for="username" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">
                Series Name:
            </label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <input type="text" data-id="123" class="form-control-plaintext input-lg" style="height: 39px; width:100%;" name="twseries" id="twseries" size="45" />
    </div>
    <br><br>
    <label for="default" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">
                Set as Default:
            </label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <input type="checkbox" name="main_ar_tw" data-id="123" style="width: 5%;height: 34px;" value="Yes" /><br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="option-group aiopsettings" data-setting-id="araiop123" style="display:none">
  <div class="form-group row" style="padding: 10px;">
    <label for="username" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">
                Campaign ID:
            </label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <input type="text" class="form-control-plaintext input-lg" style="height: 39px; width:100%;" name="aiopid" id="aiopid" size="45" />
    </div>
    <br><br>
    <label for="default" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">
                Set as Default:
            </label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <input type="checkbox" name="main_ar_aiop" style="width: 5%;height: 34px;" value="Yes" /><br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('select').change(function() {
  var dataId = $(this).attr('data-id');
  var selectedOpt = $(this).val();
  // This is the settings div. Do whatever you want
  var $elm = $('*[data-setting-id="' + selectedOpt + dataId + '"]');
  $(".option-group").hide();
  $elm.show();
  //$elm.removeClass("show");
})
```

[Here's the updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kuLm3xn1/4/)

Note that there are really a number of different ways that you could accomplish this.  What I'm giving you here may not be the best or most efficient.  I'm just giving you a quick answer using as much of your provided code as possible.

Comment: Fantastic @PatrickQ that actually works :) I will test it in the foreach loop and get back to you.

Comment: I have added the remaining options Patrick but it only seems to be working for the first two options. https://jsfiddle.net/kuLm3xn1/5/

Comment: @jay32mcr It looks like you messed up your HTML when you edited it.  You're missing a `</div>`  at the end of your "aiopsettings" section.  From what I can tell, that's the only one that's missing, but you should double-check that all your opening tags have matching closing tags.

Comment: lol how did i miss that? Seems to be working now https://jsfiddle.net/kuLm3xn1/6/